# running C# application on PC without having .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I prepared a C# application that reads from registry and saves result in a simple notepad file. I tried to run it on another PC that doesn't have .net Framework. It gave initialization error because of not having .net Framework. The problem is that I can't install .net framework on that PC which has Win XP. Is there any way that I can run this application without having .net framework??
Please help as I need it urgently>>>....

Comment: Nope.  A .NET application needs .NET to run.  You can target an earlier version of the framework when you compile, that way it'll run on a version that can be installed on XP.

Comment: Probably not the answer you are looking for but this may be the push you need to upgrade that computer, Windows XP is no longer receives updates from Microsoft and as you have no seen, it is has more restrictions with technologies

Answer (score 2):

Latest windows OS is normally packed with a default .Net Framework. Windows XP is packed with

**XP**

- `NET v1.0`  Service pack 1
- `NET v2.0` -- Service packs 2 & 3

If it's not necessary for you to use latest version of .net Framework then you could change the `target .Net Framework` of your application[Go to Project Properties > Application > Target framework] to lowest version that default OS version has then you should be able to run your program without installing latest .net framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Actually, the installed version on the target PC doesn't have .net. And It's not allowed to install any version of framework....

Comment: @ModernAgriculture: Then you picked the wrong development platform.  You could just as easily ask "How do I run my iOS app on Windows XP?" and the answer would be the same.  You don't.  Either you need to change the target environment to support the application or you need to change the application to support the target environment.

Answer (score -1):

Pack .NET DLLs with the application.

In reference section set copy on build.

Right click on reference (e.g. System.Web) and press F4. Rest is pretty self-explainatory.

Comment: Thanks for this...
But can you please advice me on how to know which DLL's I need? and how I can exactly get them....
Appreciate your reply

Comment: And how will those DLLs, which are MSIL binaries, be understood by a target machine which doesn't have .NET on it?

Comment: I tried to cut the dll files from .net framework and copy them in a backup folder
I tried to run the application after that and it ran successfully..
Do you mean the dll files with same name as when I write using in the application" i.e : using system;" means the system.dll file?

Comment: @ModernAgriculture Not exactly. When you are saying MSBuild to copy References to you bin folder and if your current architecture is specific (x86, x64, not Any CPU) than it puts correct binaries to your bin folder. You can took it without thinking .NET framework existence on target PC.